# С помощью чего реализовать мобильное приложение на основе сайта?

Tags: android, ios

Всем привет! Передо мной встала задача - нужно реализовать приложение, которое брало бы контент с моего сайта и выдавало в удобной для пользователя форме. Я не хочу пользоваться автоматическими "строителями" веб-приложений для мобильных платформ, так как, насколько я понял, они просто генерируют что-то наподобие браузера, в котором есть доступ лишь к мобильной версии указанного сайта. Пока лишь предполагаю, что нужно подключить набор сервисов (API) и делать всё это дело на его основе. При этом, приложение под андроид будет писаться на Java.

Сайт стоит на VPS сервере с конфигурацией ubuntu + nginx + php7.0-fpm + MySQL.

CMS сайта: DataLife Engine (DLE)

**Сам вопрос:** в какую сторону мне смотреть для достижения поставленной цели? Есть ли какие-нибудь "плюшки", упрощающие разработку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Под iOS лучше писать на Swift. Плюшек нет, если хотите чисто нативно на иос написать. С чего начать? Советую учиться по какому-то одному источнику, в которой есть программа, иначе можно надолго закопаться в туториалах в которых нет структуры. Источника на русском языке, к сожалению, не подскажу.

Кстати, на счет андроид, если вы не знаете Java, то возможно проще вам будет учить Kotlin.

Comment: @Tunv Fam, Java + Pascal = Kotlin :D от джавы не уйти )

Answer (score 0):

если уже есть сайт, то можно использавать [Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/).

есть [проет темплейт](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/cordova/) для Visual Studio.

есть 2 варианта:

1. гибридный (HTML и JavaScript)
2. [Hosted Web App](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/create-a-hosted-app/): в этом случае на самом деле рабтает веб сайт, он просто заворачивается (wrapping) и получается мобильное приложение.